# AX 2012 AIF Outbound port Data Policy - override mandatory fields

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, aif

I'm on AX 2012 R3 CU10.

I need to export Items data in XML format.

I've created an outbound AIF port, based on service operation `EcoResProductService.read`.
While selecting Data policies, AX won't let me untick the checkbox for `/EcoResProduct/Product/Translation/LanguageId` (grayed out), because that is a mandatory field in the underlying table.
This can be overridden by adding it to the `initMandatoryFieldsExemptionList` method of the AxBC class. Example [here](https://axfactory.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/set-mandatory-non-mandatory-fields-in-xml-message-aif-2012/)

So, I've overridden it on `\Classes\AxEcoResProductTranslation\initMandatoryFieldsExemptionList`

```
protected void initMandatoryFieldsExemptionList()
{
    super();

    // LanguageId not mandatory
    this.setParmMethodAsNotMandatory(methodstr(AxEcoResProductTranslation,parmLanguageId));

}
```

However, the checkboxes in Data policies still remain grayed out after that.
Things I've tried:

- Forward compile of modified `AxBC` class
- Incremental CIL
- Restart AOS
- AX Client config > tab:Connection >
  button:Refresh configuration

When I compare my code to standard code, like on `AxAssetTable`, there the `initMandatoryFieldsExemptionList` is implemented and works correctly.
`AssetId` is not grayed out in the data policies for that one.

Does anyone know how to make AX "see" my exemption for LanguageId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the system to update the AIF schema table. You can do this by right clicking on the service in the AOT under Services and clicking Add-Ins/Register service, or open the form AifService and click the Refresh button to update all services.